# How to find expected value?

Tags: probability, statistics

$P(X=1,Y=1) = 1/3 $
$P(X=2,Y=1)=0 $
$P(X=3, Y=1)=1/6 $

$P(X=1,Y=2) = 0 $
$P(X=2,Y=2)=0 $
$P(X=3, Y=2)=0 $

$P(X=1,Y=3) = 1/6 $
$P(X=2,Y=3)=0$
$P(X=3, Y=3)=1/3 $

If I am given the following values, how do I find the $E(XY)$, where $E$ is the expected value?

My plan is to find $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ and multiply them. But it doesn't seem to be the correct answer. I am lost can someone help me?

Comment: What is the definition you have for the expected value of a random variable ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have $E(XY)=E(X)\cdot E(Y)$, in general.

You can compute $E(XY)$ by the formula
$$
E(X\cdot Y)=\sum_{x=1}^3\sum_{y=1}^3 x\cdot y\cdot P(X=x\;\text{and}\; Y=y).
$$

You end up with $E(XY)=1/3+3/6+3/6+9/3=13/3$.